# How to insert a line break and grab data inside foreach loop

Tags: tcl

I have a set of fields to parse from a file and Im doing it line by line inside a foreach loop, i want to know how i can skip a line and go to the next line

For example :  if encounter a string called "ABC", i need to grab a number in the next line,

```
some characters "ABC" 
123
```

The problem is I'm actually having a lot of numbers in the file but i need to grab a number, specifically the number which is after a line break after the string "ABC".

How can i do this
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit easier to do with a `while` loop, reading one line at a time, since you can then easily read an *extra* line when you find your trigger case (assuming you don't have a run of lines with `"ABC"` in them):

```
set fd [open $theFilename]
while {[gets $fd line] >= 0} {
    if {
        [string match *"ABC"* $line]
        && [gets $fd line] >= 0
        && [regexp {\d+} $line -> num]
    } then { # I like to use 'then' after a multi-line conditional; it's optional
        puts "Found number $num after \"ABC\""
    }
}
close $fd
```

The reason this is awkward with `foreach` is that it will always process the same number of elements each time through the loop.

If you're dealing with data which can have the run-of-lines issue alluded to above, you are actually better off with `foreach` curiously enough:

```
set fd [open $theFilename]
set lines [split [read $fd] \n]
close $fd
foreach line $lines {
    incr idx; # Always the index of the *next* line
    if {
        [string match *"ABC"* $line]
        && [regexp {\d+} [lindex $lines $idx] -> num]
    } then {
        puts "Found number $num after \"ABC\""
    }
}
```

This works because when you do `lindex` of something past the end, it produces the empty string (which won't match that simple regular expression).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this simple solution

```
set trigger 0
set fh [open "your_file" "r"]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} { 
    if {[regexp -- {"ABC"} $line]} {
        incr trigger
    continue
    }
    if {$trigger > 0} {
        puts $line ; # or do something else
        incr trigger -1
    }
}
close $fh
```